# Outsourcing iPhone Game Development

Tags: outsourcing

I'm looking for good sources to outsource virtually every aspect of an iPhone game:

Writing
Graphics
Programming

I have a good amount of programming experience so putting everything together should not be a problem.

What are some reputable sources for outsourcing this kind of development?
Is it feasible to approach game development from this angle?

Comment: This is not a question about game development.  It is actually a question about how to _avoid_ game development.

Answer (score 6):

The way you have phrased your question implies to me that you intend to break up each subcomponent of the game and farm that out to an individual outsourcing entity (somebody gets the graphics, somebody gets the physics, somebody else gets the audio, et cetera). That seems fraught with peril -- you will need to spend an inordinate amount of time making extremely clear, detailed requirement and design specifications to give to each outsourcing entity in order to have a prayer of integrating everything without doing significant reworking on your own -- thus wasting money and probably defeating the purpose of outsourcing anyhow.

It's more feasible to essentially pay a single somebody to develop the entire game. **You can find outsourcing companies [via Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=outsourcing+game+development), unfortunately I don't know of a reputable directory of such companies.** You *might* have some luck at the [Help Wanted forum on GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net/forum/8-help-wanted/), although I wouldn't hold my breath.

You may be able to handle outsourcing every component individually if you do them one at a time, and you write the core game yourself (basically providing a design and hooks for a rendering API, and having somebody else fill it out, et cetera).

I feel like you're vastly underestimating the amount of iteration and clean up that is going to go into outsourcing code development, and when you add that to the cost (because you'll get what you pay for) **I'd be willing to bet that outsourcing that much of the game's development is not financially viable** for indie game development. If you were a large studio, perhaps the overhead would be amortized a bit.

Answer (score 1):

It may be some stupid to say this, but anyway: aren't you looking for a scriptable game engine?

This way all internal aspects of the application will be handled by the engine itself and you can just join the parts (art, AI, levels) that you can generate on your own or, if it seems more convenient for you, contract with someone else.

If all the outsourced parts work on the same toolbox and you establish a robust set of specifications I think this could be, if not easy, at least not impossible.

Also if, as you mentioned, you have programming experience it should be quite easy for you to work over an engine.

As an example I would point you to the omnipresent [UDK](http://www.udk.com/).

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the editing, and sorry about my faults, English is not my mother language. =)